# Call 2 JavaScript functions for one checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I've got a little problem, my checkbox already has an ID, Name etc. attached to it, so I don't know how to link the JavaScript code below to the checkbox, because the ID and Name are already used. I already know that you cannot use multiple IDs, because it will then only use the first ID specified.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('checkboxdelay').checked = true;
},1000)
```

```html
<input name="product" value="199" type="checkbox" id="p4" id="checkboxdelay" onChange="totalIt()"/>
```

Comment: It's not clear what actual problem you have.

Comment: I think your implementation is incorrect and should be changed and you shouldn't have the two IDs. But to add two event listeners select the checkbox using a document.querySelector, for example by adding a class name and using addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to select one element in different ways to attach different  javascript code, But if you want to call it in a different way you can always assign a class to it and identify element with javascript method: document.getElementsByClassName('classname')

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxdelay')[0].checked = true;
},1000)
```

```html
<input name="product" value="199" type="checkbox" id="p4" class="checkboxdelay" onChange="totalIt()"/>
```